# Unable To Pass Image View As Parameter in Function That Populates Recycler View with Many Image Views

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, imageview

I have written a function to populate various image views in a recycler view, nothing wrong with the function its working fine. But its too long (lets say if I have 20 Image Views). I want to make a small function and make it DRY/re-usable. But while doing that I am unable to figure out how to pass imageview as a paramter in the function. Now before you go donwvoting or get yourself in a knot, think clearly what I am asking and answer so that code can be made reusable, do not try to make it work another way because the function is already working.

The function declaration is

```
private void updateIcons(ViewHolder viewHolder) {

    if (blockStatus == null || blockStatus.equals("not_blocked")) {

        viewHolder.ivBlock.setImageResource(R.drawable.block);

    } else if (blockStatus.equals("blocked")) {

        viewHolder.ivBlock.setImageResource(R.drawable.unblocked);

    }

    if (hideStatus == null || hideStatus.equals("visible")) {

        viewHolder.ivHide.setImageResource(R.drawable.hide);

    } else if (hideStatus.equals("hidden")) {

        viewHolder.ivHide.setImageResource(R.drawable.show);

    }

    if (notificationStatus == null || notificationStatus.equals("allowed")) {

        viewHolder.ivMute.setImageResource(R.drawable.mute);

    } else if (notificationStatus.equals("muted")) {

        viewHolder.ivMute.setImageResource(R.drawable.unmute);

    }

    if (pinSequence == null || pinSequence.equals("none")) {

        viewHolder.ivPin.setImageResource(R.drawable.pin);

    } else if (pinSequence.equals("pinned")) {

        viewHolder.ivPin.setImageResource(R.drawable.unpin);

    }

    if (privacyStatus == null || privacyStatus.equals("unlimited")) {

        viewHolder.ivLimit.setImageResource(R.drawable.limit);

    } else if (privacyStatus.equals("limited")) {

        viewHolder.ivLimit.setImageResource(R.drawable.unlimited);

    }

    if (reportStatus == null || reportStatus.equals("not_reported")) {

        viewHolder.ivReport.setImageResource(R.drawable.report);

    } else if (reportStatus.equals("reported")) {

        viewHolder.ivReport.setImageResource(R.drawable.reported);

    }

}
```

The function calling is

```
updateIcons(viewHolder);
```

Following is what I am trying to do but can't pass reusable imageviews as a paramter into the function.

```
private void updateIcons(ViewHolder viewHolder, String statusValue, String checkValue1, String checkValue2,
                         int image1, int image2) {

    if (statusValue == null || statusValue.equals(checkValue1)) {

        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(image1);

    } else if (statusValue.equals(checkValue2)) {

        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(image2);

    }

}
```

**The Correct Answer Based On Mike M.'s suggestion**

The function

```
private void updateIcons(ImageView imageView, String statusValue, String checkValue1, String checkValue2,
                         int image1, int image2) {

    if (statusValue == null || statusValue.equals(checkValue1)) {

        imageView.setImageResource(image1);

    } else if (statusValue.equals(checkValue2)) {

        imageView.setImageResource(image2);

    }

}
```

And then calling it

```
updateIcons(viewHolder.ivBlock, blockStatus, "not_blocked" , "blocked",
        R.drawable.block, R.drawable.unblocked);
```

Comment: Don't pass the `ViewHolder` to that method. It doesn't care about the `ViewHolder`, only the `ImageView`. Change the first parameter to `ImageView imageView`, and call it like `updateIcons(ivBlock, ...)`. Then, inside the method, `imageView.setImageResource(...);`, like I was trying to explain last time.

Comment: Your suggestion is correct and led me to the answer, but it would have been nicer if you gave a more clear answer with some written code, not all of us are gifted with an intuition like yours.  But thanks a lot, it will save me a few hundred lines of codes per file.

Comment: You could've asked for clarification, rather than deleting your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Correct Answer Based On Mike M.'s suggestion

The function

```
private void updateIcons(ImageView imageView, String statusValue, String checkValue1, String checkValue2,
                         int image1, int image2) {

    if (statusValue == null || statusValue.equals(checkValue1)) {

        imageView.setImageResource(image1);

    } else if (statusValue.equals(checkValue2)) {

        imageView.setImageResource(image2);

    }

}
```

And then calling it

```
updateIcons(viewHolder.ivBlock, blockStatus, "not_blocked" , "blocked",
        R.drawable.block, R.drawable.unblocked);
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to get images using one of this powerful libraries ( Glide , Picasso , Fresco )